# How can I improve my pipeline efficiency?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, continuous-delivery

I need to create a parallel pipeline that has the following steps:

- Execute the Integration Tests;
- Generate the Integration Tests HTML Report;
- Publish the Integration Tests HTML Report on Jenkins;
- Generate the Integration Tests HTML Coverage Report;
- Publish the Integration Tests HTML Coverage Report on Jenkins;
- The same steps for integration tests also should be done to mutation tests;
- Deploy the application (jar file) to a pre-configured staging server (Tomcat Server instance);
- Perform a automatic smoke test that will consist in performing a curl to check if the base URL of the application is responsive after deployment;
- A UI Acceptance Manual Test will be performed in the following way. A user will be notified of the successful execution of all the previous tests and be asked to perform a manual test. In order to cancel the progression or proceed, a UI Acceptance Manual Test must take place. The pipeline should wait for a user manual confirmation on Jenkins;
- A tag shall be pushed to my SCM ( Source Control Management) repository with the Jenkins build number and status.

For now I only a initial design of what I want my pipeline to be like.
I took the decision to generate and publish the Javadoc in parallel with the mutation and integration tests since these tests don't need the Javadoc to be done.
I think that I can parallelize my pipeline more, what do you guys think and what's your opinion on my desing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your Pipeline is already well-optimized. IMHO trying to parallize it further will not yeild better performance, rather will add more complexity to the Pipeline.